# octal number divisible by $3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how many positive $3$-digit base $8$ numbers have a digit sum that is divisible by $3$ and the number, when written in base $10$, is also divisible by $3$?

Octal numbers with $3$ digits count to $7\times8\times8 = 448$, every $3$ of them are divisible by $3$, so floor $448/3=149$. Some of them in base $10$ are divisible by $3$, some not - haven't been able to find a pattern so far.

This looks more like a programming problem - but it is in middle school math contest so shouldn't require too high level knowledge.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: "*the number*, ***when written in base 10***, *is also divisible by 3*" $\;-\;$ What is that supposed to mean? A number is (or is not) divisible by $3$ regardless of how you choose to write it. For example, fifteen is divisible by three, whether you write it as $15_{10}$ in decimal, $17_8$ in octal, or $XV$ in roman numerals.

Comment: Shouldn't the largest 3-digit octal number be 777?

Comment: What you've written is a bit confusing , but it seems clear that the goal is to think through the usual test for divisibility by $3$ using base $8$ numbers.  It is not true, of course, that the number is divisible by $3$ if and only if its digit sum  is divisible by $3$ (that's true in base $10$, but not in base $8$). But you can discover a similar rule for base $8$ and use it to solve your problem.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs  I'm guessing the OP meant to write $7\times 8\times 8=448$.  I agree it is very poorly written.

Comment: @dxiv, I wonder whether OP means, the number, written in octal but *interpreted* in base ten, is divisible by three. E.g., 15-octal is 13-decimal, so not divisible by three, but 15-octal interpreted as 15-decimal is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's probably what the OP means, but it's not what they wrote, and it would serve the question well to clarify that in the post.

Comment: OK, user, it's up to you to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

Let our number's octal expansion be $abc$, which means the number (writing in base $10$ now) equals $64a+8b+c$. Reducing that expression modulo $3$, we get $a-b+c$.

Thus, this question is asking, for how many choices of $(a,b,c)$, with $\{a,b,c\}\subset\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $a\ne 0$, do we have both congruences:

$$a+b+c\equiv 0\pmod3 \\ a-b+c\equiv 0\pmod3$$

Those two expressions can't be equivalent to each other unless $b\equiv_3 0$, and then we have $a+c\equiv_3 0$. Thus, our choices for $b$ are $\{0,3,6\}$, and our choices for the pair $(a,c)$ are $$\{(1,2),(1,5),(2,1),(2,4),(2,7),(3,0),\\(3,3),(3,6),(4,2),(4,5),(5,1),(5,4),\\(5,7),(6,0),(6,3),(6,6),(7,2),(7,5)\}$$ A choice among $3$ options and a choice among $18$ options gives a total of $54$ possibilities.